# There is a MaxRecursionError during the execution of pyinstaller

Tags: python, cython, pyinstaller, setuptools

There is a MaxRecursionError when I try to convert a package to a encrypted binary file.

But I package the source code to a binary without encryption, the result is successful.

It's the content of my directory:

```
directory/
    run.py # as an entry to import package
    setup.py # import setuptools and cython
    my_pkg/
        __init__.py
        module1.py
        module2.py
        ...
```

It's the content of run.py, it just runs simple actions.

```
import my_pkg

app = my_pkg.module1.Module1()
print(id(app))
```

To do that, firstly I use `setuptools` to convert the .py files into .so files, and the output is an .egg file

```
$ python setup.py bdist_egg
```

Then I package the .egg file and run.py to a binary file using `pyinstaller`

```
$ pyinstaller run.py --onefile
```

During the process, it occurred `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison...`

Comment: It'd be super useful to see the entire run and error output.

Comment: ＠hack
I have add the content of run.py and error message.